# How do I deploy a program to Solana - Solana/Rust

Tags: solana

I am attempting to run the HelloWorld solana program. I have cloned [this](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld.git) repo. I have started the project with

```
solana-test-validator
```

I ran `npm install` and then was able to build the rust project with

```
npm run build:program-rust
```

I can see the `.so` file in the directory `/dist/program/helloworld.so`. When I try to deploy the program to solana, I run

```
solana program deploy dist/program/helloworld.so
```

And here is the error I get

```
Error: Dynamic program error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It can't find the file, but I have verified it is there. I have tried the full path and get the same error. I have tried to `clean` and reinstall the libs, but it hasn't helped.

What else should I try?

Comment: There's no code in your question. You should probably ask on the forums or issue trackers of this specific tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to make sure of:

1. The localhost (as opposed to devnet) is set via `solana config set --url localhost`
2. You have generated a new keypair `solana-keygen new`

Comment: I was pointe to the mainnet. I changed to localhost and everything worked as it should.

Comment: Glad it all worked out, if you're ever unsure what environment your config is set you can run the command `solana config get`

Comment: You can see if an account already exist in the `~` home directory. You can do that using `$ solana address`. Also, one should check its balance via `$ solana balance` to deploy a program. Or else, create a new keypair & get some free airdrop from `devnet`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the specific advises stated in the other answer, it might be also helpful to try [Solana Playground (beta)](https://beta.solpg.io/) browser based  Solana IDE. It makes entire process way smoother.

Features:

- New Project (Native, Anchor, Seahorse/Python)
- Auto airdrop
- Basic editing
- Import/Export
- Build
- Deployment
- Embedded wallet (or you can also use Phantom)
- Network settings

Hope you find it handy!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to create a new solana keygen and use solana config get to check your config file. (Optional) You can use solana-keygen pubkey and solana-keygen verify to check your wallet. Set the keypair if the location of the keygen is incorrect. Set the deployed url to devnet. Airdrop 2 sol to your wallet. Use solana balance to check whether the config keypair/wallet is correct.

1. solana-keygen new --outfile /root/solana/my_wallet.json
2. solana config get
3. solana config set --keypair
4. solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com
5. solana airdrop 2
6. solana balance (address)

Hope this can help you in config your file.